# How to remove querystring part from Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri in C#

Tags: c#, query-string

I want to remove the Querystring part from my Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri before the Redirect in C#.

For example, if you have got your

```
Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri = "http://localhost:8080/english/index_2011.aspx?logout=true"
```

Now I want to

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri) without QueryString part (?logout=true")
```

Please suggest using C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.Substring(0,Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf('?')));</strike>

**EDIT**

In fact, you can actually use:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
```

Check it out on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.URI.ABSOLUTEPATH%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true).

Comment: Why we are using -1, it is removing 'x' from my aspx extension

Answer (score 11):

use `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Split('?')[0]`

This should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 10):

A cleaner way would be

```
Request.UrlReferrer.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)
```

Meaning I want everything up to the path. It should return

```
"http://localhost:8080/english/index_2011.aspx"
```

Comment: Yes, but how could it return just /english/index_2011.aspx